# label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/user/TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

[image: Error image]

I tried many solutions online, but none of them worked.

These are the files in the 640x640 directory

[image]

Due to my mistake the files are named as 1.jpg.jpg instead of 1.jpg. But I didn't change it, since I would also have to change the contents in the xml files.

Comment: Please provide some code, and paste errors rather than screenshot them.

Comment: Could you please specify which code you meant?